# I noticed a very strange behavior in my Angular application

Tags: angular6, eventsource

enter code hereSo I am using the data that I get from the getDashboardsSEE method in the service layer. The lines for accessing the data:

```
this.dashboardService.getDashboardsSSE().subscribe(data => {

  if(data.length > 0) {
    this.dashboards = data;
    this.currentDashboard = this.dashboards[0].id;
    this.communicationService.setDashboard(this.currentDashboard);  
    this.noDashboard = false;
  }
});
```

The getDashboardsSSE uses EventSource for getting the data. It first pushes all the stream to an array and then return this array as an observable.
The getDashboardsSSE method:

```
    getDashboardsSSE(): Observable<any[]> {
    let dashboards = []
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let eventSource = new EventSource(this.sseUrl);
      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        let dashboard = JSON.parse(event.data);
        dashboards.push(dashboard);
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if(eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.next(dashboards);
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('Error: ' + error);
        }
      };

    });
  }
```

The problem here is that the page only renders when I click on something like pressing F12 or clicking on other clickable items in the page. Has anyone notices this behavior before. This doesn't happen when I use the get the data from the standard REST endpoint using the http object. Has anyone got this problem before and how did you work around it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you call getDashboardsSSE when an event happens? When do you trigger it?

Why not:

```
const dashboardObserver = this.dashboardService.getDashboardsSSE();
const subscription = dashboardObserver.subscribe(data => {
if(data.length > 0) {
    this.dashboards = data;
    this.currentDashboard = this.dashboards[0].id;
    this.communicationService.setDashboard(this.currentDashboard);  
    this.noDashboard = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: That it is called on the ngOnInit method.

Comment: It is the same implementation anyway so it doesn't work. It isn't a data problem but  it seems that it is a binding problem to the html that resolves whenever I try to resize the window or pres F12 or press other clickable buttons on the page.

Comment: Can you check with a console.log if ngOnInit is called immediately?

Comment: After the ``dashboards.push(dashboard);`` you might need ``observer.next(dashboards); observer.complete();``eventSource.readyState === 0 is the connecting state.

Comment: Yes, it is called because I have checked the execution of all the lines during the subscription.

Comment: Also I do not want to call those two line after I push the dashboard because I want to get from the observer all the data not the data incrementally 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Also yes I yse the connection state because I want the event source to end when trying to connect again to get the second stream.